# ram swap is slowing down laptop after 5.3.0-42 upgrade

Tags: release-hera, swap

i am kind of neewbie on linux elementary os, but it worked excellent until two days ago, when i downloaded an upgrade in appcenter.

since then, it shows a ram swap of 6gb/2gb, and my laptop is now constantly freezing, or slowing down, when i watch movies, play music, or games. this never happened before, i'm gessing a bug in swap. i have read about etc/fstab file to be modified to render the ram swap null but it does not work.

i should have 8gb of ram, but instead my free -h command tells me that:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5,7G        1,1G        3,8G         83M        842M        4,4G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

what can i do to restore my ram to 8gb?